# I am trying to use a for loop to add to a number, but it's not working quite right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game where objects are placed randomly in a line. Some objects have different widths so I want to space them out differently for each object. Event though my code should increment the numbers by the hundreds, it only goes up by about 5 to 15. It is important to note that no matter what my numbers are, the numbers in the debug log always show about the same and that this is originally how I wanted my numbers to be, but I changed it because the obstacles weren't instantiating properly.

```
    public float bL = 105f;
    public float aL = 155f;
    public float bM = 55f;
    public float aM = 105f;
    public float bO = 50f;
    public float aO = 55f;
    public float b5 = 50f;
    public float a5 = 155f;
    public float b3 = 50f;
    public float a3 = 55f;
    public float bT = 55f;
    public float aT = 105f;

        void Start()
    {
        float[] before = { bL, bM, bO, b5, b3, bT };
        float[] after = { aL, aM, aO, a5, a3, aT };
        //                                         ----------------------------Long Obstacle------------------------------                       ------------------------------Medium Obstacle--------------------------------               ---------------------------------------Normal-----------------------------------                  ----------------------------------OneTwoThree-----------------------------------                -----------------------------------Trisqueezy--------------------------------
        Vector3[] postition = new[] { new Vector3(-3f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(3f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(-6f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(6f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(-7f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(7f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(6f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(6f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(6f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation), new Vector3(0f, 1f, zLocation) };
        GameObject[] obstacles = { ObstacleL, ObstacleM, Obstacle, OneTwoThree, Trisqueezy, TightSqueeze };

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            obsIndex = RandomNum(0, 6);
            posIndex = obsIndex * 3 + RandomNum(0, 2);
            zLocation = zLocation + before[obsIndex];
            Instantiate(obstacles[obsIndex], postition[posIndex], Quaternion.identity);
            zLocation = zLocation + after[obsIndex];
            //prints numbers like 60, 65, 75...
            Debug.Log(zLocation);
        }
```

Any ideas? I've also included an image of the obstacles, because I believe there's also a separate, but related problem there. I've turned off some visual effects for clarity too.[image: Obstacles spawn too close even for what numbers I'm given, I think.]

Comment: Sounds like you have numbers in the inspector of this object different from the defaults you have in the code. Please include a [mre] which includes all inspector configuration needed to reproduce the problem. See [ask] for more help.

Comment: You know that anyway changing the `zLocation` value afterwards won't change the vectors you already stored in the `position` array using its original value, right?

Comment: I did not know that. That helps quite a bit. Thank you for the information. I'm just starting out so the little things are still difficult for me. I'll get right on trying to find a fix. I already have some ideas.

Comment: Actually quite simple: `var randomPosition = postition[posIndex]; randomPosition.z = zLocation;` then use this `randomPosition` later on ;) still as Ruzihm mentioned .. it sounds like you might have changed the values in the Inspector so please double check them there